# How find this maximum of $f(n)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

let $x_{i}\in (0,1),i=1,2,\cdots,n,x_{n+1}=x_{1}$,give for any positive integer numbets $n$, find 
$$f(n)=\max{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}(1-x_{i+1})}$$

find the $f(n)$

it is easy find when $n=1$, then 
$$f(1)=\max{x_{1}(1-x_{1})}=\dfrac{1}{4}$$

when $n=2$
$$f(2)=\max{\left(x_{1}(1-x_{2}),x_{2}(1-x_{1})\right)}\le\dfrac{1}{4}?$$

$$\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots$$

so I can't any work,Thank you everyone

Comment: Consider treating the sum as a function in $n$ variables, and maximize it on the open set $(0,1)^n$.

Comment: I mean we find $f(n)=$

Comment: Your “$,$” in the formula for $f(2)$ should be a “$+$”, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let

$$g(x_1,\dots,x_n):=\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} (1-x_{i+1} ). $$

We want to compute the gradient $\nabla g$ of $g$ at $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in (0,1)^n$ to find the extrema of $g$.

To do so, we start by summarizing the following facts:

1. the variable $x_1$ appears in $g$ only in the monomials $x_1(1-x_2)$ and $x_n(1-x_1)$.
2. the variable $x_n$ appears in $g$ only in the monomials $x_{n-1}(1-x_n)$ and $x_n(1-x_1)$.
3. Any other variable $x_i$, with $2\leq i \leq n-1$ appears in $g$ only in the monomials
   $x_{i-1}(1-x_i)$ and $x_i(1-x_{i+1})$.

From this it follows that

$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}=1-x_2-x_n, $$
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n}=-x_{n-1}+(1-x_1), $$
and
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}=-x_{i-1}+(1-x_{i+1}), $$

for all $2\leq i \leq n-1$.

Comment: You are welcome. Then solve the equations $\nabla g=0$ and try to prove that what you found is a maximum. It is easier if you begin with $n=3$, which has solution $x_1=x_2=x_3=0.5$.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "analytic approach" then the fastest way is to note that the function
$f(x_1,x_2,.....x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_{i+1}$ is linear with respect to each variable $x_i$ for $n\ge 2.$ Since for linear function the maximum is always attained at the end point of the interval, then all your $x_i'$ are either $0$ or $1.$

Comment: for $n=2$, $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2-2x_1x_2$ as $x_{2+1}:=x_1$. Then the gradient of $f$ is zero at $x_1=x_2=0.5$.

Comment: and? the maximum is attained at $x_1=1,$ $x_2=0$ though, provided we consider the problem on the closed interval $[0,1].$ Otherwise,$\max$ has to be replaced by the supremum.

Comment: but the problem is on $(0,1)^n$, as stated on top of the OP.